# Symfony2 dependent dropdown ManyToMany

Tags: ajax, forms, symfony, dynamic

I have 3 entities: Company, Industry, Category 
I would like to create a form where the user can input the name of the company and then selects the Industry from a dropdown list. Every Industry has Categories. When user selects a Industry I want to populate the Category list. I've read following article: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#cookbook-form-events-submitted-data

I've created the form but when the ajax call is triggered I get following error:

```
Neither the property "categories" nor one of the methods "setCategories()", "__set()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "ebulucu\MainBundle\Entity\Company"
```

I'm on this now many days and just can't get it work. I hope somebody have some hints for me. I need a form with one input field for the company name, two dropdowns Industry and Category where Category depends on the selected Industry. Company has a ManyToMany relation to Category and Industry has a OneToMany relation too category. So far this is my code:

Edit:
I have tried the code with OneToMany instead ManyToMany relation between Company and Category.
That works fine. But what to do in case ManyToMany Relation? How to manage to load and set Categories?

my 3 entities:

```
class Company
{
/**
 * @var integer
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $name;


/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Category", mappedBy="companies")
 */
private $categories;

/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->categories = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}

... setters and getters

class Industry
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=80)
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @var
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Category",mappedBy="industry")
 */
private $categories;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->categories = new ArrayCollection();
}

...setters and getters

class Category
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=80)
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Industry", inversedBy="categories");
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="industry_id", referencedColumnName="id",nullable=false)
 */
private $industry;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Company", inversedBy="categories");
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="categories_companies")
 */
private $companies;

... setters and getters
```

My Company Form Class:

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use ebulucu\MainBundle\Entity\Industry;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class CompanyRegistrationFormType extends AbstractType
{

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('name');
    $builder->add('industry', 'entity', array(
        'mapped'    => false,
        'class' => 'ebulucuMainBundle:Industry',
        'property' => 'name',
        'empty_value' => 'Choose industry',
    ));

    $formModifier = function(FormInterface $form, $industry_id) {

        if($industry_id) {
            $form->add('categories', 'entity', array(
                    'class' => 'ebulucuMainBundle:Category',
                    'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use ($industry_id) {
                            $query = $er->createQueryBuilder('i')
                                ->select(array('i'))
                                ->where('i.industry_id = :industry_id')
                                ->setParameter('industry_id', $industry_id)
                                ->orderBy('i.name', 'ASC');

                            return $query;
                        },
                    'empty_value' => 'Choose category'
                )
            );
        }
    };

    $builder->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
        function(FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
            $formModifier($event->getForm(), null);
        }
    );

    //** Checks for Industry that is submitted and adds categories based on industry selection **//
    $builder->get('industry')->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, function(FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
            $industry_id = $event->getData();
            $formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $industry_id);
        }
    );
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'ebulucu\MainBundle\Entity\Company',
        ));
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'company';
}

}
```

The Controller:

```
use ebulucu\MainBundle\Entity\Company;
use ebulucu\MainBundle\Form\Type\CompanyRegistrationFormType;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use ebulucu\MainBundle\Entity\Industry;
use ebulucu\MainBundle\Entity\Category;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class MainController extends Controller
{

 /**
 * @Route("/", name="homepage")
 * @Template()
 */
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $company = new Company();
    $form = $this->createForm(new CompanyRegistrationFormType(), $company);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('fos_user_security_login'));
    }

    return array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    );
}

/**
 * @Route("/", name="loadIndustryCategories")
 * @Template()
 */
public function loadIndustryCategories(Request $request)
{
    $company = new Company();
    $form = $this->createForm(new CompanyRegistrationFormType(), $company);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    return array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    );
}

}
```

Twig Template with form and ajax call:

```
{% block content %}
<div>Homepage</div>
{{ form_start(form, {'attr': {'id': 'form_industry'}}) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
{% endblock %}


{% block js%}
<script>
$('#company_industry').change( function() {

    var postData = $("#form_industry").serializeArray();
    var formURL = {{ path('loadIndustryCategories') }};
    $.ajax(
            {
                url : formURL,
                type: "POST",
                data : postData,
                success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
                {
                    //data: return data from server
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                {
                    //if fails
                }
            });
    e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
    e.unbind(); //unbind. to stop multiple form submit.

});
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: do you have a setCategories method in your company entity?

Comment: no I have add-, remove- and getCategories

Comment: you need a setCategories function in your company entity.  the form handler basically compiles the collection for you and then tries to assign it to the entity field.

Comment: Now I have changed the relation between company and category from ManyToMany to OneToMany and the code does work. But how I can manage the same with ManyToMany Relation and arrayCollection?

Answer (score 0):

`Company:categories` will be a collection of entities, not a singular entity, so it shouldn't have a `setCategory` method, otherwise you can inadvertently remove your whole collection. Instead you will have an `addCategories`, `removeCategories` and `getCategories` (this could be `addCategorie` and `removeCategorie` if doctrine generated due to its 'un-pluralization').

To fix, you need to change your `categories` form element to a type of `collection` instead of an `entity` in `CompanyRegistrationFormType`.

Just checking, should a company have one category or multiple? At the moment, your code seems to be somewhat a bit of both?

Comment: The company should have multiple categories. But on this form it should be possible to assign just one category.

Comment: That sounds a little precarious. Does setting this category remove all current associations or does it add this one to the current collection?

Comment: Thats the problem, I don't know how to set the category when I'm using ManyToMany Relation between Company and Category. How I can populate Categories when I'm using collection type? When I change the relation to OneToMany the code above works fine.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was, if a user sets a category in this form, does this wipe all the categories which are already on the company, or does it add the new one? I think this would be confusing from a UI viewpoint. To populate categories when using the collection type, you need to follow the `Adding and Removing items` section of [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html) page

Comment: This form will be for new companies, where you can add your first category.